# Does high frequency toggling a fibre signal create sidebands?

Tags: visible-light, frequency

If you amplitude modulate a radio frequency signal you get sidebands created at the carrier frequency ± the modulation frequency.

Does the same happen in a fibre optic cable when the very narrow band laser signal is modulated to carry information?

If so, does it make a difference to the answer if that modulation is just a simple binary on/off, i.e. turning the carrier on and off at a high frequency (e.g. 1 GHz for a gigabit Ethernet over Fibre).